# doctrine, query with count and concat

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine, doctrine-query

I have a query which I've builded with queryBuilder in Doctrine:

```
$results = $this->createQueryBuilder('cc')
            ->select("CONCAT('in: ', COUNT(CASE WHEN cc.direction = 'in' THEN 1 END),', out:', COUNT(CASE WHEN cc.direction = 'out' THEN 1 END)) AS summary")
            ->addSelect(['ch.name as channelName'])
            ->innerJoin('cc.channel','ch')
            ->where('cc.case = :caseId')
            ->andWhere('cc.channel IN (1,2)')
            ->andWhere('cc.office_id = :transOffice')
            ->andWhere('cc.id IN (:contactsIds)')
            ->setParameters($parameters)
            ->groupBy('ch.id')
            ->addGroupBy('cc.direction')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getArrayResult();
```

The main problem is with functions: COUNT and CONCAT. Without this select it works but with it dosen't. I'm obtaining response error:

[image]

Very similar raw sql works very well It looks like:

```
select Count(*) as number_of_contacts, channel_id, CONCAT('in: ', COUNT(CASE WHEN direction = 'in' THEN 1 END),', out:', COUNT(CASE WHEN direction = 'out' THEN 1 END)) AS summary from cic_case_contacts where case_id = 328678 group By channel_id
ORDER BY channel_id
```

but in query builder I have syntax problem.
How should I write this query in query builder properly?
I would be grateful for help.
Best regards

Comment: I don't know this API at all, but maybe you need to call a select raw function instead of what you are currently calling.

Comment: Yes, you are right I will write raw sql. It will works.